# How to implement custom renderers for Xamarin controls

Tags: c#, xamarin

Could anyone please help with the following?

I have a Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio. I have a Picker control and I want to make a custom renderer for it to centre text.

I have two projects in the solution OGLMobile and OGLMobile.Android.

In the OGLMobile.Android project in MainActivity.cs I have the following code (all compiles fine):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(OGLMobile.Droid.MyPicker), typeof(OGLMobile.Droid.BetterPickerRenderer))]

.
.
.

public class MyPicker : Picker
    {
        public MyPicker() : base()
        {
        }
    }

    public class BetterPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        public BetterPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is, how do I use this in the OGLMobile project where I want to dynamically create such a control in C# in MainPage.xaml.cs?

So whereas I now have:

```
private Picker m_picker = null;
```

I would like to have:

```
private MyPicker m_picker = null;
```

At the moment the type MyPicker cannot be found in this solution.

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: `MyPicker` needs to be defined in the shared Forms project, and the renderer(s) need to be in the platform projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jason said, put the `MyPicker` in Xamarin.forms and put the renderer in Droid platform project like below.

[image]

The renderer class in android platform project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(BetterPickerRenderer))]
namespace Test.Droid
{
class BetterPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    public BetterPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

[image]

Comment: Thank you both very much. I now have it working thanks to your clarification.

Comment: If you solved this issue, you could accept as answer. This will help people who has the same issue.